# Reduce the oracle PL/SQL statement

Tags: sql, oracle

I am a new in PL/SQL. After hours of learning, I have some 
I have a few curious questions. Example I have a SQL statement like this:

```
SELECT ShipperName, OrderID, NumberOfOrders, ... 
FROM Orders
```

Can we declare a variable that hold the "list select" like `list_select = 'ShipperName, OrderID, NumberOfOrders, ... '` 
And then replace the select statement with the "list select" we was declared?

```
SELECT list_select 
FROM Orders
```

And other question, Can we reduce the SQL statement like the Image[image: (image)] . I was try this in Oracle SQL Developer, the compiler is ok but when I ran the test I was got an error "by segment".

Any help is appreciated and thank for help.

Comment: Please do **not** post code as images. See here for more details why: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551

Comment: Please aks one question at a time. This should have been two requests: The first one on dynamic SQL (which can be solved with PL/SQL as shown in Ankit Bajpai's answer). The second one on how to optimze a query in SQL (as answered in my answer).

Comment: If you have two questions please ask **two questions** as separate posts. A thread on StackOverflow should comprise one question and (ideally) one accepted answer. This thread has two separate answers, one for each of the questions you have posted. You cant accept both of them.

Answer (score 1):

For your first question, You may search for "EXECUTE IMMEDIATE" statement which is used for dynamic query execution. So you may try something like below -

```
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'SELECT ' || YOUR_COMMA_DELIMITED_COLUMNS_LIST || ' FROM Orders';
```

For 2nd, Please post the sample data and expected result.

Answer (score 1):

For your second question: You don't want joins here, because you only select from table1. You rather want `[NOT] EXISTS` or `[NOT] IN`. E.g.:

```
SELECT orderid, clientid
FROM orders o
WHERE EXISTS -- We are looking for orders containing expensive items
(
  SELECT null 
  FROM orderposition op
  WHERE op.orderid = o.orderid
  AND op.price > 1000
)
AND -- and the client ...
(
  NOT EXISTS -- ... must have paid all their invoices (there exists no unpaid invoice)
  (
    SELECT null 
    FROM invoices i
    WHERE i.clientid = o.clientid
    AND i.paid_date IS NULL
  )
  OR clientid IN -- ... or be known as reliable client (they are in the set of reliable ones)
  (
    SELECT c.clientid
    FROM clients c
    WHERE c.reliable = 'YES'
  )
);
```